# ThreadPoolExecutor and ArrayBlockingQueue

Tags: runnable, java.util.concurrent, callable, threadpoolexecutor

Excuse me for my bad english. 
When the number of threads in the pool to rise above 10, the the task will be placed in ArrayBlockingQueue . But if the task Callable? Constructor ThreadPoolExecutor not accept ArrayBlockingQueue typed as Callable. How, then, will be added to the queue the task?

```
ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 10,
                60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that `ThreadPoolExecutor` does not add your `Callable` to the queue directly. Instead, it will wrap the `Callable` into a [RunnableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RunnableFuture.html)
via a call to the method [AbstractExecutorService.newTaskFor(Callable)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#newTaskFor(java.util.concurrent.Callable)), then add this `RunnableFuture`to the queue.